# Is there a way to return multiple unrelated results in an sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a "feed" system on my site where activity on users' posts is posted. To do this effectively and order all activity by date, I need to put everything in one huge query (unless there's another way to do this effectively). My problem is that my current "feed" page has multiple ajax calls to get all the different data such as comments on the user's post or votes on debates the user started. Is there a way to combine unrelated queries to return multiple results? For example, can I combine these two queries into one?
Query 1:

```
 SELECT articles.article_id, articles.title, articles.date, articles.idUsers, users.uidUsers, profileimages.image
FROM articles JOIN
     users JOIN
     profileimages
     ON articles.idUsers = users.idUsers AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers
WHERE articles.idUsers = '$following' AND
      articles.published = 'yes'
ORDER BY articles.date ASC";
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT polls.poll_id, polls.title, polls.idUsers, polls.date, users.uidUsers, profileimages.image
FROM polls JOIN
     users JOIN
     profileimages
     ON polls.idUsers = users.idUsers AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers
WHERE polls.idUsers = '$following'
ORDER BY polls.date ASC";
```

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a union all and add a new column 'type' on each query result.

```
SELECT 
    articles.article_id as id, 
    articles.title as title, 
    articles.date as date, 
    articles.idUsers as idUsers, 
    users.uidUsers as uidUsers,
    profileimages.image as image,
    'article' as type
FROM articles 
JOIN users  ON articles.idUsers = users.idUsers 
JOIN profileimages on  profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE articles.idUsers = '$following' AND articles.published = 'yes'

union all   


SELECT  
        polls.poll_id as id, 
        polls.title as title,
        polls.date as date,
        polls.idUsers as idUsers,        
        users.uidUsers as uidUsers,
        profileimages.image as image,
        'pool' as type
FROM polls 
JOIN users ON polls.idUsers = users.idUsers
JOIN profileimages  ON profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE polls.idUsers = '$following'
```

Then, you can create a super select to order the results as you want.

```
select * from (

    SELECT 
        articles.article_id as id, 
        articles.title as title, 
        articles.date as date, 
        articles.idUsers as idUsers, 
        users.uidUsers as uidUsers,
        profileimages.image as image,
       'article' as type
    FROM articles 
       JOIN users  ON articles.idUsers = users.idUsers 
       JOIN profileimages on  profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
    WHERE articles.idUsers = '$following' AND articles.published = 'yes'

    union all     


    SELECT  
        polls.poll_id as id, 
        polls.title as title,
        polls.date as date,
        polls.idUsers as idUsers,        
        users.uidUsers as uidUsers,
        profileimages.image as image,
        'pool' as type
    FROM polls 
        JOIN users ON polls.idUsers = users.idUsers
        JOIN profileimages  ON profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
    WHERE polls.idUsers = '$following' 

) query order by query.type, query.date
```

Performance is usually related to full table scans. Be sure that you created all indexes correctly and remember to use it in the where clause.
In the case of too many results, consider implementing query pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.

But an inner join like i used it, can produce a lot of unwanted results.

So you should use phpmyadmin or workbench....

to run one such query and see if it gives you the correct result.
If not you have to group it or add more where conditions.

```
SELECT
  t1.article_id
  ,t1.title
  ,t1.idUsers
  ,  t2.poll_id
  , t2.title
  , t2.idUsers
  , t2.date
  , t1.uidUsers 
  , t2.image
FROM
  (SELECT 
    articles.article_id
    , articles.title
    , articles.date
    , articles.idUsers
    , users.uidUsers 
    , profileimages.image 
  FROM 
    articles 
    JOIN users 
    JOIN profileimages 
   ON articles.idUsers = users.idUsers AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
  WHERE articles.idUsers = '$following' AND articles.published = 'yes' 
  ORDER BY articles.date ASC) t1
inner join
 (SELECT 
  polls.poll_id
  , polls.title
  , polls.idUsers
  , polls.date
  , users.uidUsers
  , profileimages.image 
FROM 
  polls 
  JOIN users 
  JOIN profileimages 
  ON polls.idUsers = users.idUsers AND profileimages.idUsers = users.idUsers 
WHERE polls.idUsers = '$following' 
  ORDER BY polls.date ASC) t2
on t1.uidUsers = t2.uidUsers
ORDER BY t2.date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `union all` before `join`ing, because the joins are so similar:

```
SELECT ap.article_id, ap.title, ap.date, ap.idUsers,
       u.uidUsers, pi.image
FROM ((SELECT a.article_id, a.title, a.date, a.idUsers
       FROM articles a
       WHERE a.idUsers = '$following' AND a.published = 'yes'
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT p. poll_id, p.title, p.date, p.idUsers
       FROM posts p
       WHERE p.idUsers = '$following'
      )
     ) ap JOIN
     users u
     ON ap.idUsers = u.idUsers JOIN
     profileimages pi
     ON pi.idUsers = u.idUsers
ORDER BY ap.date ASC;
```

Note `$following` should be passed in as a *parameter* not a string.